# Counting repetitions and writing on a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to compare values between N columns, row by row, on the same dataframe and set a new column counting the repetitions, when the values from the 3 columns match with another row?
From:

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3
0  | z       | x       | x       
1  | y       | y       | y       
2  | x       | x       | x       
3  | x       | x       | x       
4  | z       | y       | x      
5  | w       | w       | w     
6  | w       | w       | w     
7  | w       | w       | w
```

To:

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3 | counter
0  | z       | x       | x       | 0
1  | y       | y       | y       | 1
2  | x       | x       | x       | 2
3  | x       | x       | x       | 2
4  | z       | y       | x       | 0
5  | w       | w       | w       | 3
6  | w       | w       | w       | 3
7  | w       | w       | w       | 3
```

Something like that: `if(column1[someRow] == column1[anotherRow] & column2[someRow] == column2[anotherRow] & column3[someRow] == column3[anotherRow])` then `counter[someRow]++`

Comment: Can you break down the logic? This is currently ambiguous. Do you want `df['counter'] = df.groupby(['column1', 'column2', 'column3'], sort=False).ngroup()`?

Comment: Yeah, when the column values match, the ```counter``` iterates

Comment: I was using ```df['counter'] = df.groupby(['column1', 'column2', 'column3']).transform('count')``` but isn't working anymore

Comment: Then my suggestion above should work and you have a mistake in your output

Comment: Where I mistaken?

Comment: Why would the last row be 0? z/y/x was not seen before.

Comment: Cause there is no anyone z/y/x in this sequence on the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250834/discussion-between-null92-and-mozway).

Comment: Then why is y/y/y having a value of 1? As requested in my initial comment, please **break down** the logic (i.e., give a detailed example of how the logic works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
`df['counter'] = df.groupby(['column1', 'column2', 'column3']).transform('size')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# keep only relevant columns
df2 = df.drop(columns='id')

# are the values identical in the row?
m = df2.eq(df2.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)

# count the number of occurrences per group
# and only keep the output when all values are identical
df['counter'] = df2.groupby(list(df2)).transform('size').where(m, 0)

# for older pandas versions
# df['counter'] = df2.groupby(list(df2))[df2.columns[0]].transform('size').where(m, 0)
```

Output (with an extra row for clarity):

```
   id column1 column2 column3  counter
0   0       z       x       x        0
1   1       y       y       y        1
2   2       x       x       x        2
3   3       x       x       x        2
4   4       z       y       x        0
5   5       w       w       w        1
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'column1': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'z', 'w'],
                   'column2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'w'],
                   'column3': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'w'],
                  })
```

Comment: I'm getting all 0 at the ```counter```

Comment: I added my reproducible input, please check with this

Comment: Used on a online compiler and get: ```ValueError: No objects to concatenate```

Comment: @null92 maybe you use an older pandas version, try: `df['counter'] = df2.groupby(list(df2))[df2.columns[0]].transform('size').where(m, 0)`

Comment: I don't know why, but it works with the simple df example, but doesn't in my project =/

Comment: do you have all the columns you want in `df2`? no more no less?

Comment: I did. Try using this sample ```df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2], 'column1': ['Total', 'B2B', 'TI COMPANY'], 'column2': ['Total', 'B2B', 'TI COMPANY'], 'column3': ['Total', 'B2B', 'TI COMPANY']})```

Comment: I get 1/1/1, isn't it what you'd expect?

Comment: No, cause appears 3 times, so the output should be 3 at the counter on all 3 rows

Comment: then we're back to zero in terms of logic… each row is only present one time. **One** Total/Total/Total, **one** B2B/B2B/B2B, etc.

Comment: Ops, try with this sample: ```df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2], 'column1': ['Total', 'Total', 'Total'], 'column2': ['B2B', 'B2B', 'B2B'], 'column3': ['TI COMPANY', 'TI COMPANY', 'TI COMPANY']})```

Comment: @null92 here the 3 values in each row are different from each other, you said earlier that all values needed to be the same. If this is not the case then a simple `df['counter'] = df2.groupby(list(df2)).transform('size')` will work, without needing to compute `m`.

Comment: Did you read this new explanation: ```if(column1[someRow] == column1[anotherRow] & column2[someRow] == column2[anotherRow] & column3[someRow] == column3[anotherRow])``` then ```counter[someRow]++```.
For some reason, ```df['counter'] = df2.groupby(list(df2)).transform('size')``` are ignoring some columns. I saved ```df2``` and ```m``` as csv. ```df2``` is exactly I want to compare and ```m``` it's all ```False```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
s = df.drop("id", axis=1).nunique(1)
df["counter"] = (
    df.groupby(df.where(s.eq(1))["column1"]).transform("size").fillna(0).astype(int)
)

#For previous versions of pandas
df["counter"] = (
    df.groupby(df.where(s.eq(1))["column1"])["column1"]
    .transform("size")
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
)

print(df)

   id column1 column2 column3  counter
0   0       z       x       x        0
1   1       y       y       y        1
2   2       x       x       x        2
3   3       x       x       x        2
4   4       z       y       x        0
5   5       w       w       w        1
```

What were are doing here is get number of unique elements across axis 1 (excluding column `id`) using [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) and then take those rows which have only one unique value and do a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `size`.

Comment: ```TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types```

Comment: This is the same logic as my answer, so the same issue, you have to pass a dummy column to transform for older pandas versions ;)

Comment: Hmm same logic except I use nunique and s == 1 grouper which I think is better than list(df2) probably?

Comment: @null92 I updated answer with a second transform for previous versions. try that.

Comment: @SomeDude the nunique is equivalent to my `m`, the `list(df2)` is just to group by all columns. Anyway my comment was for OP's error due to `groupby.transform('size')` on older pandas versions ;)

Comment: @mozway grouping by all columns is not efficient compared to grouping by a single series, no?